# Extra data files appear in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

My app saves files in iCloud. By going to Settings > iCloud > Storage and Backup > Manage Storage, I can view the files that my app is saving in iCloud. For some reason, I get these extra files whose filename generally looks like this: `.dat091d.09c`. They're now taking up about 30% of the total space my app uses in the cloud, so I think it merits some investigation. What are these files, and how are they created?

Thanks!

Comment: Which iCloud API(s) are you using? There's more than one, with very different effects.

Comment: I use NSMetadataQuery to find iCloud documents. To create files, I generate a URL using the ubiquity container URL by appending the file name and then calling `NSFileManager createItemAtPath`.

Comment: That's... wrong. Go read Apple's docs on how this is supposed to work. You're supposed to create the file locally and then move it to the cloud.